# Can't iterate over collection and insert into template

Tags: meteor

I'm a beginner at Meteor, and am not able to do the simple task of iterating over a collection and printing a single attribute for each item to the template. I have autopublish turned on so I haven't written pub/sub functions. All the other components I've made so far work, so I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the code below.

In HTML (note the comment)

```
  <template name="tags">
    <div class="tags">
            {{#each printTags }}
                    {{name}} <br>
            {{/each }}
            <!-- why is nothing showing up here? -->
    </div>
  <template>
```

In JS file

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

      Tags = new Mongo.Collection("tags")

      tags = Tags.find({}).fetch();

      Template.tags.helpers({
            printTags: tags
      });
    }
```

On the client, in Dev Tools

```
    Tags.find().fetch().forEach(function(tag){console.log(tag["name"])})
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your `printTags` helper is assigned to a variable (`tags`) holding the result of fetching the collection documents when the collection is not yet filled with data.

You must use a function so the expression will be reactively re-evaluated when data is available :

```
Template.tags.helpers({
  printTags: function(){
    return Tags.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not reactive, calling .fetch() stops that. In order to use reactive data from db you must return a ```cursor```  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor

Comment: You are correct, in this case it's more appropriate to return a cursor because Blaze can optimize the #each to only re-render parts of its content. But it's not what you return inside a reactive computation that triggers reactivity, it's reactive data sources that gets evaluated and ultimately depended on, so even if you return a plain array using fetch, the helper would still be reactive because the find call triggers reactivity whatsoever.